# Unable to locate `kwallet-pam` package in Debian (bullseye) even though the package exists in the source

Tags: debian, package-management, kde, kwallet

I'm trying to install `kwallet-pam` package in my Debian 11 with KDE Plasma so that I don't need to type in wallet passcode at every boot.

But `apt update` then `apt install kwallet-pam` says `E: Unable to locate package kwallet-pam`, despite the fact that the package is in the source! : https://packages.debian.org/source/bullseye/kwallet-pam

What am I misunderstanding / how to resolve this issue?

Comment: In your link "The **following binary packages** are built from this source package" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [libpam-kwallet5](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libpam-kwallet5) package which builds upon `kwallet-pam`.

> KWallet (Kf5) integration with PAM
> The KDE Wallet system provides a secure way to store passwords and other secret information, allowing the user to remember only a single KDE Wallet password instead of numerous different passwords and credentials.
>
> This package provides a simple PAM integration for KWallet, so you can log in to open a KWallet.